# ss-utils.js returning 404 not found

Tags: servicestack

I can see ss-utils.js if I run the server locally, but on the deployed environment (AWS) I'm getting a 404 not found.

On my local I'm running on a Mac/Mono environment, whereas the AWS server is on Windows/IIS. Are there any differences in the setup for IIS to access ss-utils.js?

I have set the HandlerFactoryPath in my code:

```
Config.HandlerFactoryPath = "api"
```

So theoretically it should work when I visit /api/js/ss-utils.js however, I'm still getting the 404

This is the debug requestinfo

```
{
  "Usage": "append '?debug=requestinfo' to any querystring",
  "Host": "WebServer20_v4.050_pM",
  "Date": "2016-01-21T00:42:33.4022859Z",
  "ServiceName": "pM",
  "HandlerFactoryPath": "api",
  "UserHostAddress": "10.0.X.XXX",
  "HttpMethod": "GET",
  "PathInfo": "/js/ss-utils.js",
  "ResolvedPathInfo": "/js/ss-utils.js",
  "StripApplicationVirtualPath": false,
  "GetLeftPath": "http://uat.zzzz.com",
  "Path": "/api/js/ss-utils.js",
  "GetPathUrl": "http://uat.zzzz.com/api/js/ss-utils.js",
  "AbsoluteUri": "http://uat.zzzz.com/api/js/ss-utils.js?debug=requestinfo",
  "WebHostUrl": null,
  "ApplicationBaseUrl": "https://uat.zzzz.com/api",
  "ResolveAbsoluteUrl": "https://uat.zzzz.com/api/resolve",
  "ApplicationPath": "/",
  "ApplicationVirtualPath": "/",
  "VirtualAbsolutePathRoot": "/",
  "VirtualAppRelativePathRoot": "~/",
  "CurrentDirectory": "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\inetsrv",
  "HandlerFactoryArgs": "GET|/api|C:\\Octopus\\Applications\\UAT\\pM.ApiHost\\1.20.6016\\api",
  "RawUrl": "/api/js/ss-utils.js?debug=requestinfo",
  "Url": null,
  "ContentType": "",
  "Status": 0,
  "ContentLength": 0,
  "Headers": {
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Pragma": "no-cache",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    "Cookie": "SS_MID=960a1c12-c454-4985-8db7-8341706aa589i3XXXXX; ss_cid=7cd0127a-0cce-44cd-b248-b8b6a8XXXXXX; __utma=30576126.2094331120.1418258412.1430269692.1430807371.78; __utmc=30576126; _ga=GA1.2.2094331120.1418258412; ss-id=XXXXXX; ss-pid=XXXXXX; X-UAId=1462;,
    "Host": "uat.zzzz.com",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "X-Proxied-By": "ip-10-0-1-11",
    "X-Forwarded-For": "203.xxx.xxx.xxx, 10.0.1.11",
    "X-Forwarded-Port": "80",
    "X-Forwarded-Proto": "http"
  },
  "QueryString": {
    "debug": "requestinfo"
  },
  "FormData": {},
  "AcceptTypes": [
    "text/html",
    "application/xhtml+xml",
    "application/xml;q=0.9",
    "image/webp",
    "*/*;q=0.8"
  ],
  "OperationName": "/api",
  "ResponseContentType": "text/html",
  "ErrorCode": null,
  "ErrorMessage": null,
  "LogonUserInfo": {
    "Name": "NT AUTHORITY\\IUSR",
    "AuthenticationType": "",
    "IsAuthenticated": "False",
    "IsAnonymous": "False",
    "IsGuest": "False",
    "IsSystem": "False",
    "Groups": "S-1-1-0, S-1-5-32-545, S-1-2-1, S-1-5-11, S-1-5-15, S-1-2-0",
    "User": "S-1-5-17",
    "User.AccountDomainSid": "null",
    "User.IsAccountSid": "False"
  },
  "DebugString": "System.Web.HttpRequest|System.Web.HttpResponse",
  "OperationNames": null,
  "AllOperationNames": null,
  "RequestResponseMap": null,
  "PluginsLoaded": [
    "HtmlFormat",
    "CsvFormat",
    "MarkdownFormat",
    "PredefinedRoutesFeature",
    "MetadataFeature",
    "NativeTypesFeature",
    "SessionFeature",
    "AuthFeature",
    "RazorFormat",
    "ValidationFeature",
    "ServerEventsFeature"
  ],
  "StartUpErrors": [],
  "LastRequestInfo": {
    "HandlerType": "RestHandler",
    "OperationName": "Ping",
    "PathInfo": "/test/ping/dnshealthcheck"
  },
  "Stats": {
    "RawHttpHandlers": "3",
    "PreRequestFilters": "0",
    "RequestBinders": "0",
    "GlobalRequestFilters": "2",
    "GlobalResponseFilters": "3",
    "CatchAllHandlers": "4",
    "Plugins": "11",
    "ViewEngines": "2",
    "RequestTypes": "553",
    "ResponseTypes": "231",
    "ServiceTypes": "480",
    "RestPaths": "632",
    "ContentTypes": "5",
    "EnableFeatures": "All",
    "VirtualPathProvider": "[FileSystemVirtualPathProvider: C:\\Octopus\\Applications\\UAT\\pM.ApiHost\\1.20.6016], [ResourceVirtualPathProvider: pM.ApiHost], [ResourceVirtualPathProvider: ServiceStack]"
  },
  "VirtualPathProviderFiles": []
}
```

Request headers:

```
GET /api/js/ss-utils.js HTTP/1.1
Host: uat.zzzz.com
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Cookie: SS_MID=960a1c12-c454-4985-8db7-8341706aa589i300000; ss_cid=7cd0127a-0cce-44cd-b248-b8b6a8000000; __utma=30576126.2094331120.1418258412.1430269692.1430807371.78; __utmc=30576126; ss-id=xxxx; ss-pid=xxxx; X-UAId=1462; __ngDebug=true; _ga=GA1.2.2094331120.1418258412;
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Thu, 21 Jan 2016 23:51:45 GMT
Server: nginx
Vary: Accept
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Content-Length: 3
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 2):

[ss-utils.js](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/js/ss-utils.js) is an embedded resource inside **ServiceStack.dll** which should be available at path `/js/ss-utils.js`, e.g:

- https://servicestack.net/js/ss-utils.js
- http://test.servicestack.net/js/ss-utils.js
- http://techstacks.io/js/ss-utils.js

> All links to websites above are hosted on AWS/IIS/Windows

All [Embedded Resources](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Virtual-file-system#embedded-resources) contained in .dlls registered in `Config.EmbeddedResourceSources` or `Config.EmbeddedResourceBaseTypes` are automatically served by ServiceStack's [Virtual File System](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Virtual-file-system#embedded-resources) which by default include **ServiceStack.dll** which contains `/js/ss-utils.js` so it should automatically be available by default.

If it's not being served at `/js/ss-utils.js` then there's potentially an issue check the [Debug RequestInfo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Debugging#request-info) at `?debug=requestinfo` for any StartUp errors that may have caused invalid AppHost configuration.

#### Custom Virtual File Service

Your debug info looks fine so I would expect the request to return the file as expected. The next step would be to see if file can be resolved from the [Virtual File System](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Virtual-file-system). To test this can you add this Service:

```
[Route("/files/{Path*}")]
public class GetFile
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}

public class FileServices : Service
{
    public object Any(GetFile request)
    {
        var file = VirtualFileSources.GetFile(request.Path);
        if (file == null)
            throw HttpError.NotFound("File '{0}' does not exist".Fmt(request.Path));

        return new HttpResult(file) {
            ContentType = MimeTypes.GetMimeType(file.Extension)
        };
    }
}
```

This will let you call the following url:

```
/api/files/js/ss-utils.js
```

to return a file resolved from Virtual File System. If you added any static files, e.g `/js/ss-utils.js` please rename or remove it as would [override the Embedded Resources](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Virtual-file-system#overriding-embedded-resources-with-static-files).

Comment: our app routing seems to have been configured to use /api/ as the base. Would this have an effect?

Comment: @vonec yes the path then becomes [/api/js/ss-utils.js](http://bootstrapapi.servicestack.net/api/js/ss-utils.js)

Comment: @vonec If you're having issues make sure you specify the path in code as well, e.g. `SetConfig(new HostConfig { HandlerFactoryPath = "api" })`

Comment: yep I did use that: /api/js/s-utils.js that's how I got the 404 error. Specifying the path in code didn't work either, i.e.,  Config.HandlerFactoryPath = "api"

Comment: @vonec should work then, will need a repro to be able to investigate further (i.e. github project).

Comment: Startup errors doesn't show anything. It works when I run it locally, but on our UAT server it gives 404, there are some slight differences in the environment, e.g., UAT is using https

Comment: @vonec Impossible to tell from here, are you using a proxy or IIS virtual host mapping? Can you post the Debug request info for: `/api/js/ss-utils.js?debug=requestinfo` it might show the request is being translated into a different request when reaching ServiceStack.

Comment: I've updated the post and for the record, I really do appreciate you taking the time to help here. At the moment the workaround I'm using is to make a copy of the code and create my own ss-utils.js file. This is not ideal because when we have to do upgrades it can be forgotten.

Comment: @vonec Weird, the debug info looks normal so should work. Can you add the `FileServices` class above so you can check to see if the issue is that the file cannot be resolved. You can also preview list of files in VirtualFileSystem by adding `&virtualPathCount=n` to debug info, e.g [/api/js/ss-utils.js?debug=requestinfo&virtualPathCount=1000](http://test.servicestack.net/js/ss-utils.js?debug=requestinfo&virtualPathCount=1000) where it should ultimately return `"ServiceStack.js.ss-utils.js"`

Comment: Using the `FileServices` class works! So what does this mean?

Comment: @vonec that the file can be resolved, so it should work. I don't have any idea why you're getting a 404, are you sure the request is even reaching ServiceStack? i.e. can you post the full HTTP Request and Response Headers (using something like Fiddler or Chrome Web Inspector). You don't have any custom handlers or Request Filters that could interfere with the request right?

Comment: Updated OP with Request and Response Headers

Comment: @vonec Not seeing a `X-Powered-By:ServiceStack/..` Response Header. Maybe the request isn't reaching ServiceStack after all? It says it served by nginx and reaches ASP.NET, but it's not showing that it's reached ServiceStack? Anyway I wont be able to help any further without being able to see/reproduce the issue. You're going through multiple layers, i.e nginx reverse proxy / IIS / ASP.NET before the request reaches ServiceStack, you could have modules and HTTP Handlers and mappings interfering with the request, it's impossible for me to identify the issue from here.

Comment: No problem, I have a feeling it's something to do with the infrastructure. Thanks anyway, you've been a great help!